# oracle AQ for scheduled jobs

Tags: oracle, jobs, queue

We have a process that currently uses the Oracle DBMS_SCHEDULER to execute. The process runs every time the backend receives data from an external device. The Oracle scheduler is set up such that a job is created on reception of external data, the job executes immediately, and the job is destroyed automatically when complete.

The issue here is that multiple devices could be sending up data at the same time. Because the process involves obtaining exclusive locks at different points throughout execution, occasionally one job will step on another that is already executing (it gets rejected).

I would like to somehow use the Oracle AQ (advanced queueing) mechansim in order to solve this issue. I envision a queue of jobs that are executed FIFO. Even if external device B sends up data while the process is currently processing data from external device A, the queue prevents processing of data from device B until processing for device A is complete.

There doesn't seem to be a specific section on this type of AQ processing in the Oracle documentation, but it seems like it would be a pretty common scenario. Has anyone else solved this type of issue with Oracle AQ?

More importantly, is Oracle AQ the most efficient way to solve this problem?

Comment: I used oracle AQ to receive changes from multiple tables, queue them and then shoot the changes to another database.  There were never any issues with the modest amount of transactions I had ( <200/day).  What are you looking for: how to set up, how to queue or???

Comment: It'd be great to get a brief rundown of both setup and queuing action.  This particular problem involves a single db. The 'process' that runs will pull multiple exclusive locks depending on where it is in execution. One thought was that if the exclusive locks were named uniquely, it would allow concurrent processing to occur without the need for AQ.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "Pulls multiple exclusive locks". Are you referring to code that uses Select for update or Lock table commands? I am unaware of how you would name a lock or how that would help, more details please on the problem

Comment: The process will use different named exclusive locks throughout its execution depending on what it's doing, e.g. PLSQL procedure A will pull an exclusive lock named 'PROCEDURE_A'; after completion, the process will move to PLSQL procedure B that pull an exclusive lock named 'PROCEDURE_B'. What I'm wondering about is if concurrent processing could occur if the lock names were generated in a unique fashion, programmatically, rather than using the static name declared in the procedure, e.g. instead of 'PROCEDURE_B', use a generated unique name like 'PROCEDURE_2ug8eb'

Comment: You can use DBMS_LOCK, http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_lock.htm#i1002533 to generate unique names for your locks but the naming will not affect the type of processing.  Can you post a test case?